# SQLite create table

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Im unable to create SQLite table.

Android Studio IDE shows me error on this line "Column constrains or Comma expected, got Text"

```
String CREATE_TABLE_CONTACTS = "CREATE TABLE " + Util.TABLE_NAME + "(" +
    Util.KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + Util.KEY_NAME + " TEXT," +
    Util.KEY_PHONE_NUMBER + " TEXT" + ")";
```

Answer (score 2):

IMO your code

```
String CREATE_TABLE_CONTACTS = "CREATE TABLE " + Util.TABLE_NAME + "(" +
Util.KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + Util.KEY_NAME + " TEXT," +
Util.KEY_PHONE_NUMBER + " TEXT" + ")";
```

is ok problems belongs from `Util.TABLE_NAME` or `Util.KEY_ID` check here these key strings not having **spaces**

```
DO => user_name

DON'T => user name
```

Answer (score 1):

If your columns happen to have whitespace or other reserved words, then you may try escaping them using double quotes:

```
String CREATE_TABLE_CONTACTS = "CREATE TABLE \"" + Util.TABLE_NAME + "\" (" +
"\"" + Util.KEY_ID + "\" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, \"" + Util.KEY_NAME + "\" TEXT, \"" +
Util.KEY_PHONE_NUMBER + "\" TEXT" + ")";
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "addToCart_db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "addToCart";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
public static final String COLUMN_PRODUCT_ID = "product_id";
public static final String COLUMN_QTY = "qty";
public static final String COLUMN_PRICE = "price";

public static final String CREATE_TABLE =
        "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
                + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + COLUMN_PRODUCT_ID + " TEXT,"
                + COLUMN_PRICE + " TEXT,"
                +COLUMN_QTY +" TEXT)";
```

try it, this formatting create table